# Shifting specific elements in a 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to shift specific elements in a two dimensional array i.e. while some elements move, others stay in a fixed position. For Example:

```
char arr[][] = {{'.','.','.'},{'.','u','.'},{'x','.','.'}};
```

will be shifted to:

```
arr[][] = {{'.','u','.'},{'.','.','.'},{'x','.','.'}};
```

I have a code sample to shift all elements in the array a certain number of places up such that it wraps around from the bottom, but can't figure out how to keep the x's in a fixed position. I read all elements into a new Array.

```
public static void moveUp(char arr[][], int pos){
     for(int r = 0; r < 6; r ++){
               for(int c = 0 ; c < 5; c++){
                   newArr[(r+(6-pos))%6][c] = arr[r][c];
               }
     }
}
```

This is made on the auumption that the array has 6 rows and 5 columns.

Comment: What exactly do you want to shift? The one example you showed simply switches the 2nd element with the 1st one! Is that just a coincidence? Can you fill the array with more distinct values to show exactly what is supposed to get shifted where?

Comment: The 'u' characters are all shifted up while the 'x' characters remain fixed. The '.' characters all "fillers" for empty elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a boolean if you want the 'u' to go up and the x to stay as you commented. For example, the position of 'u' should change from char[i][j] to char[i-1][j].